# Is there a max http connection limit in WinRT application?

Tags: http, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm making a WinRT application and I found a strange behavior. I can't open more than few parallel http requests to my server. The number is about 4-6 requests ( I don't know exact number).

New requests stuck somewhere inside client app.

I have independent instances of `HttpClient` and seems they share this limit, so it's not per-client, it's per app.

I aware of http connections limit in browsers, has WinRT same behavior? How can it be tuned?

Comment: I believe it's six since the same settings are used as for IE 10.  You [can increase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282402) but not sure that's viable for a Windows Store app. You'd probably need to presume the default/worst case.

Comment: default/worst case doesn`t matter, because this app is internal and will be deployed via our server without Microsoft store (so we have full control on target machine settings)

Comment: ah well then try the registry tweak, I'll upgrade to "answer" if it works!

Comment: I know your pain. It appears to be what causes my (more recent) [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069097/why-does-httpclient-appear-to-deadlock-here). It's as if HttpClient just deadlocks somewhere internally. If I exceed probably about 4 silmultaneous requests, HttpClient stops working for the entire application. And even if you stop the requests, it still takes *minutes* for HttpClient to get back to working status.

Comment: This problem combined with their odd way of not immediately returning on error, leads to horrible behavior. Like if you are trying to tell your server something and you're not connected to the internet, the HttpClient will timeout after **1 minute and 30 seconds** and return the error code "not found". This equally occurs if the server actively refuses the connection. So basically you have to build your own "queue" of connections because the one Microsoft implemented is too poor to handle it I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that limit is per-domain.

So I set subdomains for my server`s domain and call server in round robin.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be different in Windows 8.1 as you can set the maximum number of connections via [HttpBaseProtocolFilter.MaxConnectionsPerServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.maxconnectionsperserver.aspx)

Note that this requires you use the new `HttpClient` in `Windows.Web.Http`

Comment: So... they've made another set of http classes side-by-side with `System.Net.Http`. Great. Thanks for info.