# Why does HttpClient appear to deadlock here?

Tags: c#, networking, windows-runtime, dotnet-httpclient, winrt-async

I have an API made in a portable class library which needs to reach out to platform specific APIs for sending HTTP requests. Here is the method I wrote to do an HTTP POST on WinRT:

```
   public bool Post(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers, string data)
    {
        bool success = false;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {AllowAutoRedirect = false});
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        try
        {
            var task=client.PostAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")).ContinueWith( postTask =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            postTask.Wait(client.Timeout); //Don't wait longer than the client timeout.
                            success = postTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
                        }catch {}
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning);
            task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            task.Wait(client.Timeout);

        }
        catch
        {
            success = false;
        }

        return success;
    }
```

This exhibits an interesting problem though when put under *any* kind of stress though. It appears to deadlock internally. Like if I create 5 threads and send POST requests out of them, this method will get to where it will do **nothing** but timeout. Content never reaches the server, and the `.Continue` code is never executed. However, if I run it serially or maybe even with 2 or 3 threads it will work OK. It seems that the more threads thrown at it though make the performance exponentially worse

Exactly what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you know anything about the performance monitors on the endpoint you're calling?  What's the webserver's average response time and how short is your local timeout?  It could be that under load the performance suffers enough that the timeout fires before the request returns.

Comment: @cgotberg I've tested it with a few different servers. My primary "dumb" test server is just webrick. I've also used other servers that use IIS and such. The big problem is that even in watching Fiddlr, I can see that no communications actually happen. It gets locked up somewhere before actually sending anything

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is where you problem is but it could be and it's really easy to implement and test it out.  By default Windows sets the Max Network connections to 2 and with more than 2 threads you could be locking on the connection pool.  You can add this to your app config

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="300" />
   </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

or in code you can do this

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 300
```

I'd also consider commenting out the wait in the continue with. I don't think it's necessary.

```
try
{
    //Comment this line out your handling it in the outside task already
    //postTask.Wait(client.Timeout); //Don't wait longer than the client timeout.
    success = postTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
 }catch {}
```

And finally if the 2 things above don't work I'd try commenting out the this code.

```
//Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

It could be that the combination of Task.Wait plus setting Task.ConfigureAwait(false) is causing some kind of deadlock but I'm no expert on why.  I just know that I have some really similar code that runs multi-threaded just fine and I don't have Task.ConfigureAwait(false) in my code, mostly because I tried out the HttpClient library but didn't upgrade to .NET 4.5 so await isn't available.

Comment: `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 300` did the trick for me after hours of debugging. This should have way more upvotes

Comment: Why, though? This fixed a deadlock problem I had, which is great, but why would it deadlock? Shouldn't connections in the pool get freed up as soon as a request times out?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some things that stick out to me with the current code:

- `ContinueWith` queues a delegate to run when the task is *complete*. So there's no need to wait for it.
- `LongRunning` is not needed here; it will decrease performance because your continuation is very fast, not long running at all.
- `ConfigureAwait` is meaningless because there's no `await` (and the return value is discarded anyway).
- The timeout doesn't need to be passed to `Task.Wait` because the task will already completed after that timeout anyway.

> I have an API made in a portable class library which needs to reach out to platform specific APIs for sending HTTP requests.

I recommend making your API asynchronous since it's doing HTTP. You can use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` if you want full `async`/`await` support in PCLs.

```
public async Task<bool> Post(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers, string data)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {AllowAutoRedirect = false});
    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }

    try
    {
        var result = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't. This is implementing an interface that has to work with pre .Net 4.5 code (and no we can't pull in that one async library for .Net 4). Also, this transmission occurs on another thread *anyway* so we won't really gain anything by making it async other than cleaner code

Comment: @Earlz: `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` provides `async` for .NET 4 as well as PCLs.

Comment: That still doesn't fix our requirement that we can't use libraries outside of the framework :(

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this HttpClientHandler issue as well when multiple requests are issued concurrently. (.NET Framework 4.7.2)

I was able to resolve the issue by backporting the .NET Core 2.1 SocketsHttpHandler to .NET Framework and the [backported implementation](https://github.com/TalAloni/StandardSocketsHttpHandler) significantly improved performance when dozens of multiple requests are issued concurrently.